# What is causing this template-related compile error?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

When I try to compile this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class ZUniquePool
{               
        typedef std::map< int, T* > ZObjectMap;
        ZObjectMap      m_objects;
public:
    T * Get( int id )
    {
        ZObjectMap::const_iterator it = m_objects.find( id );
        if( it == m_objects.end() )
        {
            T * p = new T;
            m_objects[ id ] = p;
            return p;
        }
        return m_objects[ id ];
    }
};

int main( int argc, char * args )
{
    ZUniquePool< std::string > pool;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘T* ZUniquePool<T>::Get(int)’:
main.cpp:12: error: expected `;' before ‘it’
main.cpp:13: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

I'm using GCC 4.2.1 on Mac OS X.
It works in VS2008.

I'm wondering whether it might be a variation of this problem:
[Why doesn't this C++ template code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364837/why-doesnt-this-c-template-code-compile)
But as my error output is only partially similar, and my code works in VS2008, I am not sure.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `typename`:

```
typename ZObjectMap::const_iterator it = m_objects.find( id )
```

Since the type of `ZObjectMap` is dependent on the template parameter, the compiler has no clue what `ZObjectMap::const_iterator` is (it could be a member variable).  You need to use `typename` to inform the compiler to assume it will be some sort of type.

Comment: Fantastic! Not only did you solve my problem, but you also made me realize something fundamentally important about the way templates are treated by the compiler.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

*Also to mention, **GCC 4.5.0** gives the following output which would help you to solve the problem:*

```
main.cpp: In member function 'T* ZUniquePool<T>::Get(int)':
main.cpp:12:7: error: need 'typename' before 'ZUniquePool<T>::ZObjectMap:: const_iterator' because 'ZUniquePool<T>::ZObjectMap' is a dependent scope
main.cpp:12:34: error: expected ';' before 'it'
main.cpp:13:11: error: 'it' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:23:5: warning: second argument of 'int main(int, char*)' should be 'char **'
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep that in mind for future template compile errors (switching to newer versions of GCC that is).