# C++ class template inheritance puzzle

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

What's wrong with this code? gcc 4.6.1 is complaining "‘foo’ was not declared in this scope" in baz(). If I transform the code so that one of the templates is just a regular class, the problem goes away.

```
struct Foo {
    char foo;
};

template<int N>
struct Bar : public Foo
{
    Bar() { foo; }
};

template<int N>
struct Baz : public Bar<N>
{
    void baz() { foo; }
};

int main() {
    Baz<10> f;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to do here - Bar() {foo;} What is foo?

Comment: This is called dependent name. See http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#base-lookup

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this C++ template code compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364837/why-doesnt-this-c-template-code-compile)

Comment: badmaash, you sound like a compiler. :) foo is the foo from the class Foo, inherited by Bar, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong, according to the specifications, I don't know, but you may make your code to compile by using:

```
void baz() { Bar<N>::foo; }
```

Comment: What is wrong, is that while compiling `Baz` it doesn't know _which_ `Bar<N>` to inherit from yet (there might be specializations later), so it doesn't yet know there is a `foo` member.  By qualifiying it, you're telling it that `Bar<N>` will have the `foo` member, and not to worry about it until `N` is known.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is a dependent name; that is, it depends on the template parameter, so until the template is instantiated the compiler doesn't know what it is. You have to make it clear that it is a class member, either `Bar<N>::foo` or `this->foo`.

(You probably also want to do something with it; simply using it as the ignored value of an expression doesn't do anything at all).